# FuseIT WSDL Parser - Error generating Apex Classes

Tags: apex, fuseit

I'm receiving the following error when parsing a wsdl we've used for java and .net c# applications.  I understand the parsing is different for both the Salesforce apex generator and the FUSEIT wsdl2apex generator, but hoping I can get some help.

I'm receiving the following error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:objectToConvert.

The wsdl used is below.

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://custkeyservice.webservices.itsos.americancentury.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:ns1="http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService" name="CustKeyServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://custkeyservice.webservices.itsos.americancentury.com/">
  <wsdl:import location="http://aserver:8081/SpiService/services/CustKeyService?wsdl=CustKeyServicePortType.wsdl" namespace="http://aserver:8081/CustKeyService">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="CustKeyServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:CustKeyServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCrmById2">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getCrmById2">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getCrmById2Response">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCrmByCustId">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getCrmByCustId">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getCrmByCustIdResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCrmById">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getCrmById">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getCrmByIdResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustKey">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getCustKey">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getCustKeyResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CustKeyServiceImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:CustKeyServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="CustKeyServiceImplPort">
      <soap:address location="http://aserver:8081/SpiService/services/CustKeyService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>`

The wsdl import is specified below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService" name="CustKeyServicePortType" targetNamespace="http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService">
      <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService" version="1.0">

<xs:element name="getCrm">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>    
      <xs:element name="getCrmByCustId">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCrmByCustIdResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="out" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCrmById">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCrmByIdResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="out" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCrmById2">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCrmById2Response">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="out" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCrmResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="out" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCustKey">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="getCustKeyResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="out" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmByCustIdResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmByCustIdResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmByCustId">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmByCustId" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmById2Response">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmById2Response" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCustKey">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCustKey" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmById2">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmById2" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmById">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmById" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCustKeyResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCustKeyResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getCrmByIdResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmByIdResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="CustKeyServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="getCrmById">
          <wsdl:input message="ns1:getCrmById" name="getCrmById">
        </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output message="ns1:getCrmByIdResponse" name="getCrmByIdResponse">
        </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getCrmByCustId">
          <wsdl:input message="ns1:getCrmByCustId" name="getCrmByCustId">
        </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output message="ns1:getCrmByCustIdResponse" name="getCrmByCustIdResponse">
        </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getCrm">
          <wsdl:input message="ns1:getCrm" name="getCrm">
        </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output message="ns1:getCrmResponse" name="getCrmResponse">
        </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getCrmById2">
          <wsdl:input message="ns1:getCrmById2" name="getCrmById2">
        </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output message="ns1:getCrmById2Response" name="getCrmById2Response">
        </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getCustKey">
          <wsdl:input message="ns1:getCustKey" name="getCustKey">
        </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output message="ns1:getCustKeyResponse" name="getCustKeyResponse">
        </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the complete WSDL. It is missing the `binding` and `service` elements. The `service` element should also define a `port` element.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete WSDL? Feel free to change the port URL.

Comment: I've updated the wsdl provided.

Comment: Can you also provide the import form http://aserver:8081/SpiService/services/CustKeyService?wsdl=CustKeyServicePortType.wsdl please.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - This is included now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully completed this code effort myself.  I took a look at their example and their explanation from the apex guide and recreated what was needed for my own WSDL.

I then was able to wire this together with my controller and use the mock web service also documented from the guide to implement my test classes. Lastly, I had the http auth headers included for when I call the webservice to ensure it's secure.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated WSDL:**

I needed to add, what I assume is the definition of, the `getCrm` message which was still missing.

```
<wsdl:message name="getCrm">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrm" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

After that I was able to generate the following Apex classes that can deploy successfully to Salesforce.

**NOTE:** If the namespaces etc... don't match the actual WSDL you will likely get errors when trying to use it against the real web service.

acdt14038080Custkeyservice:

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)

public class acdt14038080Custkeyservice {
    public class getCrm_element {
        public String id;
        private String[] id_type_info = new String[]{'id','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'id'};
    }
    public class getCrmByCustId_element {
        public String id;
        private String[] id_type_info = new String[]{'id','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'id'};
    }
    public class getCrmByCustIdResponse_element {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class getCrmById_element {
        public String id;
        private String[] id_type_info = new String[]{'id','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'id'};
    }
    public class getCrmById2_element {
        public String id;
        private String[] id_type_info = new String[]{'id','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'id'};
    }
    public class getCrmById2Response_element {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class getCrmByIdResponse_element {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class getCrmResponse_element {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class getCustKey_element {
        public String id;
        private String[] id_type_info = new String[]{'id','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'id'};
    }
    public class getCustKeyResponse_element {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','string','1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
}
```

custkeyserviceWebservicesItsosAmeri:

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
//Methods Included: getCrmById, getCrmByCustId, getCrm, getCrmById2, getCustKey
// Primary Port Class Name: CustKeyServiceImplPort  
public class custkeyserviceWebservicesItsosAmeri {
    public class CustKeyServiceImplPort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://acdt1403:8081/SpiService/services/CustKeyService';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService','acdt14038080Custkeyservice'};

        public String getCrm(String id) {
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrm_element request_x = new acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrm_element();
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.id = id;
            Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrm',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmResponse',
                'acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }

        public String getCrmByCustId(String id) {
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByCustId_element request_x = new acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByCustId_element();
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByCustIdResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.id = id;
            Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByCustIdResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByCustIdResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmByCustId',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmByCustIdResponse',
                'acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByCustIdResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }

        public String getCrmById(String id) {
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById_element request_x = new acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById_element();
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByIdResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.id = id;
            Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByIdResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByIdResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmById',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmByIdResponse',
                'acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmByIdResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }

        public String getCrmById2(String id) {
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById2_element request_x = new acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById2_element();
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById2Response_element response_x;
            request_x.id = id;
            Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById2Response_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmById2',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCrmById2Response',
                'acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCrmById2Response_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }

        public String getCustKey(String id) {
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCustKey_element request_x = new acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCustKey_element();
            acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCustKeyResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.id = id;
            Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCustKeyResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCustKeyResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCustKey',
                'http://acdt1403:8080/CustKeyService',
                'getCustKeyResponse',
                'acdt14038080Custkeyservice.getCustKeyResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Original Issue:**

The operation `getCrm` takes an input message of the same name.

```
<wsdl:operation name="getCrm">
  <wsdl:input message="ns1:getCrm" name="getCrm">
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output message="ns1:getCrmResponse" name="getCrmResponse">
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

**There is no corresponding wsdl:message with the name "getCrm".**

Compare this to getCrmResponse, which has:

```
<wsdl:message name="getCrmResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="ns1:getCrmResponse" name="parameters">
  </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<xs:element name="getCrmResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="out" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So, as presented in the question there are sections of the WSDL missing.

Comment: you're correct, I left that portion off.  I added the xs:element section back to my original post. That's what happens when I try to edit the originally generated wsdl.  Thanks for pointing that out, hopefully we can keep working towards a solution.

Comment: When I try to include these in the tool, the input parameters name is null, which I think is the issue.  Every other tool I've used always makes the input parameter java.lang.String with a name of id.